# How to pass string concatenation to function in f#

Tags: f#

How to pass string concatenation operator (I do not want to use `^`) to function?

If I try to create variable:
`let x = (+)` compiler says x is of type `int -> int -> int`. How can I annotate x so it works on strings?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED QUESTION:** To answer your updated question - the `+` operator is generic and uses static member constraints to work on any type that supports it. This gets lost if you use it in a function or assign it to variable. The one way to keep this property is to define an `inline` function.

```
let x1 = (+)               // Type constrained, because it's not a function
let x2 a b = (+)           // Type constrained, because it's not `inline`
let inline x3 = (+)        // Error: only functions can be `inline`
let inline x4 a b = a + b  // Works and you can use `x4` with strings and ints
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** There must be something else going on in your situation that you are not showing in your question. If you just open a new F# script file, the following works:

```
let funInt (f:int -> int -> int) = f 1 2
let funStr (f:string -> string -> string) = f "hi" "there"

funInt (+)
funStr (+)
```

Now, I'm not sure what else you have in your code that is causing the error. One possibility I can think of is if you re-defined the `+` operator - if you have a new definition that is not `inline`, you'll get the error you describe:

```
let funInt (f:int -> int -> int) = f 1 2
let funStr (f:string -> string -> string) = f "hi" "there"

let (+) a b = a + b

funInt (+)
funStr (+)
```

Can you post a minimal reproducible example that illustrates the issue?

Comment: Thomas now I see my sample code had no sense, because compiler know that `funStr` works on strings. I wanted to know how to get string version of + operator, so compiler correctly types my function - updated question to reflect that.